# Generator of two-qubit quantum gate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, group-theory, quantum-computer

I would like to know how to derive the explicit form of the GENERATOR of a [general two-qubit gate](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0308006.pdf) (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate)), e.g., controlled-rotation Y.

From the definition: $$\exp(-i\theta G) \ ,$$

I see it is: $$G=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-i\\0&0&i&0\end{pmatrix} \ ,$$

but, I would like to know how to write it in the form of [Pauli Y operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).

Many thanks.

[Update]
The question is about if a unitary two-qubit gate is given, how to derive its generator explicitly. For instance, if we look at a Molmer Sorenson gate, we will immediately know its generator is XX or YY or ZZ. For Controlled rotation gate, if we do the calculation $-\log[U]/(i\theta)$, we have the G in the main text. The problem is how to write it in form of Pauli-Y and identity matrix (with tensor product or other operation).

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: Are you trying to write it in block matrix form?

Comment: I typeset your equation for you, but I think it may be incorrect. In particular, I think the top left block should be $I$. Please edit the question accordingly if you agree

Comment: Thanks but I think if the top left is I instead of 0, $exp(i\theta G)$ will let top left diagonal elements be $exp(i\theta)$ :)

Comment: @yvubinotctyui Actually, could you clarify what is $G$?

Comment: One concern I have with the gate you have currently written is that it is not unitary, and has determinant $0$ - if applied to $|00\rangle$, for example, it would cause the state to disappear!

Comment: The matrix you gave isn't controlled Y rotation. If you want to know how to write controlled Y as a matrix or in terms of Pauli matrices, think about what the instruction "do a Y rotation on qubit 2 if qubit 1's Z observable has value 1 and -1 if it is -1" should look like.

Comment: Come on, the matrix I typed is the generator of controlled RY....

Comment: @yvubinotctyui Don't be disrespectful. Make the post as clear as possible.

Comment: Your matrix you gave is NOT a valid gate bcs it doesnt preserve unitarity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but the thing you exponentiate to get a controlled $Y$ gate,
$$ \mathsf{CY} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1} + Z \otimes \mathbb{1} + \mathbb{1} \otimes Y - Z \otimes Y \right)$$
is simply
$$ G = \frac{1}{4} \left( \mathbb{1} - Z \right) \otimes \left( \mathbb{1} - Y \right),$$
which is the projector onto the $-1$ eigenstates of $Z$ and $Y$ for the respective qubits, so that
$$ \mathsf{CY} = e^{- i \pi G}.$$
The matrix representation of this differs from what you wrote in your question, but will generally depend on the choice of basis for the two-qubit system.

To answer your more general question, I suggest looking at the two answers to [this question on the QC stack exchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15403/what-hamiltonians-generate-hadamard-and-cnot-matrices). Any controlled-something gate will certainly involve the Pauli $Z$ on the first qubit.

Comment: Fine, I did the math only for controlled-unitary gate. In the case of CRY gate, we know the generator of Ry is Y. Then we have $G=(I-Z)\otimes Y$ for the generator of this two-qubit gate...